NLS function does not work when a factor variable is added
I am fitting a model using nls for two separate years and I want to see if the response is different between years so I tried the following:
set.seed(123)

n <- 40

y <- runif(n, min = 0, max = 1)
x <- exp(0.5 * y) + rnorm(n, mean = 0, sd = 0.1)
z <- runif(n, min = 0, max = 1)
year <- rep(c(2022, 2023), each = 20)

data <- data.frame(x = x, y = y, z = z, year = factor(year))

model1 <- nls(
 x ~ (1 - z / a) * b * exp(c * y),
 data = data,
 start = list(a = 0.01, b = 0.01, c = 0.01),
 algorithm = "port",
 lower = c(a = 0.01, b = 0.01, c = 0.01),
 upper = c(a = 2.5, b = 2, c = 2)
)

but if I want to run the interaction of year I get an error because a factor can not be multiplied by a number in an nls
model2 <- nls(
 x ~ (1 - z / a) * b * exp(c * y)*year,
 data = data,
 start = list(a = 0.01, b = 0.01, c = 0.01),
 algorithm = "port",
 lower = c(a = 0.01, b = 0.01, c = 0.01),
 upper = c(a = 2.5, b = 2, c = 2)
)

but in the answer of this question Fitting nls model with a categorical variable they can add a factor to the nls and get a result to then be compared using an ANOVA (my final goal)
Am I setting the formula or the argument wrong?
Thanks for all the help in advance
*Data is a dummy data

You can use nlme::gnls. It uses treatment contrasts.
set.seed(123)

n <- 40

y <- runif(n, min = 0, max = 1)
z <- runif(n, min = 0, max = 1)
year <- rep(c(2022, 2023), each = 20)

#simulate a better response
x <- (1 - z / ifelse(year == 2022, 2, 5)) * ifelse(year == 2022, 10, 5) * exp(ifelse(year == 2022, 3, 2) * y) + rnorm(n, mean = 0, sd = 0.1)

data <- data.frame(x = x, y = y, z = z, year = factor(year))

library(nlme)

fit <- gnls(
  x ~ (1 - z / a) * b * exp(c * y),
  params = a + b + c ~ year,
  start = c(2, 3, 10, -5, 3, -1), 
  data = data
)
summary(fit, cor = FALSE)
#Generalized nonlinear least squares fit
#  Model: x ~ (1 - z/a) * b * exp(c * y) 
#  Data: data 
#        AIC       BIC   logLik
#  -70.84037 -59.01821 42.42018
#
#Coefficients:
#                  Value  Std.Error   t-value p-value
#a.(Intercept)  1.999266 0.00423215  472.3997       0
#a.year2023     3.029269 0.08928492   33.9281       0
#b.(Intercept)  9.988462 0.01975596  505.5923       0
#b.year2023    -4.960741 0.03263828 -151.9915       0
#c.(Intercept)  3.001897 0.00205869 1458.1592       0
#c.year2023    -1.011522 0.00627034 -161.3186       0

anova(fit)
#Denom. DF: 34 
#              numDF   F-value p-value
#a.(Intercept)     1 176320049  <.0001
#a.year            1   2552017  <.0001
#b.(Intercept)     1 106701124  <.0001
#b.year            1   5550012  <.0001
#c.(Intercept)     1   2603692  <.0001
#c.year            1     30616  <.0001

In the ANOVA and summary table only the p-values of *.year parameters (difference between years in the respective parameters) are of interest. The null hypothesis that parameters are equal to zero is often not sensible for non-linear parameters (i.e., the *.(Intercept)).
You can also do a likelihood-ratio test (provided the optimizer converges without the year variable):
fit0 <- nls(x ~ (1 - z / a) * b * exp(c * y),
                start = c(a = 2, b = 10, c = 5), 
                data = data)

anova(fit, fit0)
#     Model df      AIC      BIC     logLik   Test  L.Ratio p-value
#fit      1  7 -70.8404 -59.0182   42.42018                        
#fit0     2  4 384.8928 391.6483 -188.44638 1 vs 2 461.7331  <.0001

AFAIK, the nlme package doesn't support parameter boundaries.

I don't think that the port algorithm supports the subscripting notation shown in the link.  Use ifelse instead:  Also do not use starting values on the boundary.
nms <- c("a22", "a23", "b22", "b23", "c22", "c23") 
st <- setNames(rep(0.2, 6), nms)
lower <- setNames(rep(0.1, 6), nms)
upper <- setNames(c(2.5, 2.5, 2, 2, 2, 2), nms)

model2 <- nls(
 x ~ ifelse(year == 2022, (1 - z / a22) * b22 * exp(c22 * y),
   (1 - z / a23) * b23 * exp(c23 * y)),
 data = data,
 start = st, lower = lower, upper = upper,
 alg = "port")

giving
model2
## Nonlinear regression model
##   model: x ~ ifelse(year == 2022, (1 - z/a22) * b22 * exp(c22 * y), (1 -     z/a23) * b23 * exp(c23 * y))
##    data: data
##    a22    a23    b22    b23    c22    c23 
2.5000 2.5000 1.4109 1.1007 0.2952 0.5947 
##  residual sum-of-squares: 1.395
##
## Algorithm "port", convergence message: relative convergence (4)

anova(model1, model2)
## Analysis of Variance Table
##
##     Model 1: x ~ (1 - z/a) * b * exp(c * y)
##     Model 2: x ~ ifelse(year == 2022, (1 - z/a22) * b22 * exp(c22 * y), (1 - z/a23) * b23 * exp(c23 * y))
##       Res.Df Res.Sum Sq Df  Sum Sq F value Pr(>F)
##     1     37     1.5631                          
##     2     34     1.3950  3 0.16805  1.3653 0.2699

The p value here is invalid because the a parameters are on the boundary.  We can fix a in the model and run with the default parameters and algorithm conditional on a.
a <- 2.5

model3 <- nls( x ~ (1 - z/a) * b * exp(c * y), data,
 start = list(b = 0.2, c = 0.2))

model4 <- nls( x ~ (1 - z/a) * b[year] * exp(c[year] * y), data,
  start = list(b = c(0.2, 0.2), c = c(0.2, 0.2)))

which gives these model outputs
model3
## Nonlinear regression model
##   model: x ~ (1 - z/a) * b * exp(c * y)
##    data: data
##      b      c 
## 1.2387 0.4488 
##  residual sum-of-squares: 1.563
##
## Number of iterations to convergence: 6 
## Achieved convergence tolerance: 2.549e-07

model4
## Nonlinear regression model
##   model: x ~ (1 - z/a) * b[year] * exp(c[year] * y)
##    data: data
##     b1     b2     c1     c2 
## 1.4109 1.1007 0.2952 0.5947 
##  residual sum-of-squares: 1.395
##
## Number of iterations to convergence: 5 
## Achieved convergence tolerance: 5.033e-06

and running the anova:
anova(model3, model4)
##   Analysis of Variance Table
##
## Model 1: x ~ (1 - z/a) * b * exp(c * y)
## Model 2: x ~ (1 - z/a) * b[year] * exp(c[year] * y)
##   Res.Df Res.Sum Sq Df  Sum Sq F value Pr(>F)
## 1     38     1.5631                          
## 2     36     1.3950  2 0.16805  2.1684 0.1291

